# why the consumer thread only executes when the producer has finished writing 10 objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not able to understand why the consumer thread executes only when the producer has finished writing 10 objects. If I see it according to the javadoc a thread be executed only if the synchronized block is complete yet, I don't think in the below case the block is complete because the execution goes in a loop inside synchronization block.

As per java doc notify method comment

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

```
        Runnable consumer = (() -> {
            synchronized (BUFFER) {
                while(true) {
                try {
                        while(BUFFER.isEmpty()) {
                            BUFFER.wait();
                        }
                        System.out.println("consuming "+BUFFER.poll());
                        System.out.println("size "+BUFFER.size());
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        BUFFER.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            }});

        Runnable producer = (() -> {
            synchronized (BUFFER) {
                while(true) {
                try {
                    while(BUFFER.size() == 10) {
                        BUFFER.wait();
                    }
                    Random random = new Random();
                    System.out.println("producing "+BUFFER.offer(random.nextInt()));
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    BUFFER.notify();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                }
        }
        });

        executor.submit(consumer);
        executor.submit(producer);


OUTPUT

producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
producing true
consuming 1494680650
size 9
consuming 2055368049
size 8
[comment]: SUCCESS: Assembly.Load(ProcMonInject, Version=2.7.5159.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d34a061f079be347)
consuming 569414348
size 7
consuming -1146378118
size 6
consuming -2025680888
size 5
consuming -1624438827
size 4
consuming -2035450589
size 3
consuming 953341046
size 2
consuming 776364558
size 1
consuming -2019340509
size 0
producing true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You call BUFFER.notify() from producer thread, consumer thread will be woken up and will try to acquire the lock on Buffer object. But producer thread still has the lock for the buffer object (so consumer has to wait for it to be released). When producer fulfill the condition `while(BUFFER.size() == 10)` it will release the lock on the buffer object. 
This time consumer will acquire the lock and will consume the buffer. Until it fulfill the condition `while(BUFFER.isEmpty())` and release the lock.

For information purposes; Producer-consumer can be written without using locks, with the [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) class. (If You give a capacity to the queue, producer thread will be blocked when capacity is full. Consumer thread will be blocked when there is no item in queue.)

Comment: does wait() method releases lock and gives it to other thread. From what I have read, wait() method lets the thread wait till it gets notified. And in the above case notify of producer won't exectue since the producer is  in a loop when the BUFFER has 10 objects.

Comment: @BeginnersSake wait method releases the lock. If there are threads that are waiting to acquire that lock object, one of them will acquire it(others will be blocked until the locked gets released again). In Your current code when producer enter that loop it will release the lock. And when producer has a chance to continue, buffer will be empty.(because consumer will consume everything before releasing the lock.)

Comment: @BeginnersSake Javadoc for `wait()` clearly says that it releases the lock

Comment: Thanks @ivan I went through the javadoc for wait()  and got to know thread releases ownership of the monitor once wait() is executed. I was confused because of the notify(). I thought it wakes the thread but the execution only starts when the synchronization block is complete. I never thought of wait method itself giving up the ownership of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

The producer is sleeping while inside the synchronized block.

Try this instead:

```
 Runnable producer = (() -> {
            while(true) {
                synchronized (BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        while(BUFFER.size() == 10) {
                            BUFFER.wait();
                        }
                        Random random = new Random();
                        System.out.println("producing "+BUFFER.offer(random.nextInt()));
                        BUFFER.notify();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
        });
```

With the same modification for the consumer.

Comment: From what I have read, the notify() wakes up the other thread but it would only execute when the thread is free from the synchronization block. As I have a loop in my synchronization block, I don&#39; think the other thread should execute at all. Let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @BeginnersSake `notify()` wakes up arbitrary thread that waits on a lock. Usually call to `notify()/notifyAll()` is the last line in synchronized block as thread which calls `notify()/notifyAll()` should release lock **before** thread which is woken up would try to acquire the same lock.